# MongoDB save and increment field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to save daily statistics with the number of message sent using WhatsApp using MongoDB, using mongoose / NodeJS.
According to document, using $inc, if the entry not exist a new is created.
But no one document is created when running this code.

I have this model

```
const mongoose = require('../database');

const StatWpSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        require: true,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        require: true,
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    }
});

StatWpSchema.index({
    userId: 1,
    date: {
        index: true,
        sparse: true
    },
});

const StatWp = mongoose.model('StatWp', StatWpSchema);

module.exports = StatWp;
```

And the code to save the statistics.

```
const statWp = require('../models/statWp');

let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

statWp.findOneAndUpdate(
   { userId: _userId, date: today },
   { $inc: { quantity: 1 } },
   { upsert: true },
   function (err, response) { }
);
```

Comment: use `upsert: true`: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#upsert

Comment: If it works, rollback your edit and add a self-answer.